# Unresolved external symbol from unkown source

Tags: c++

I have been learning c++ programing and I have been making simple codes. Sometimes this LNK2019 error appers when everything seems to be correct in my code. Aparently I have some kind of symbol not defined? I am unsure about the source of the error. Does anyone know what the error can be about?
For context, all I am testing is the mathematical operations of Microsoft Visual Studio.

Edit: the error message that pops up is:
"external symbol not resolved, main, refered in fuction "int_cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    cout << 5 + 7 << endl;
    cout << 5 * 7 << endl;
    cout << 5 / 7 << endl;
    cout << 5 - 7 << endl;
    cout << 10 % 3 << endl; 
    cout << 5 + 7 * 2 << endl; 

    
    int x = 5;
    float y = 3.7;
    float z = x + y;

    
    cout << x + y << endl;
    cout << z << endl;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to show the full error message, not just tell us there's a link error. It could be anything. The program you have posted compiles fine. My crystal ball tells me your link error might be related to a missing `WinMain` function, which is common when accidentally configuring a project as an application when it is intended to be a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Sometimes** this LNK2019 error appers

You are probably seeing this error:

> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Which means you are missing a definition for `main`. If you try to build your program, but haven't gotten around to implementing `main()` that is what you will see in Visual Studio.

Next time you see it, check to make you have defined either:

```
int main()
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

In your current example, your code is fine.